Nuxt3: useAsyncData + $fetch + watch , can't send cookie header when watch value changed
I want to fetch data from middleware server with cookie.
When I opened the first page, I fetched data without error. But page number changed (currentPage.value changed and watch acted), error occured.
I checked packets with Wireshark. When I opened the first page, Nuxt sent cookie headers.
but I clicked another page number and watch acted, Nuxt didn't send cookie headers.
How can I set cookie header?
const currentPage = ref(1);
const { data } = await useAsyncData(
  "middleware-data",
  () =>
    $fetch("/path/xx.json", {
      method: "GET",
      baseURL: targeturl,
      headers: useRequestHeaders(["cookie"]),
      params: {
        page: currentPage.value,
      },
    }),
  { watch: [currentPage] }
);

wireshark fetch 1st page

wireshark fetch 2nd page


useRequestHeaders(['cookie'])  is used for server-side cookies and document.cookie is used for client-side
can you try by document.cookie?

@miltonbhowmick, Thank you for your comment.
I changed cookie value,  useRequestHeaders(['cookie'])  to {"cookie":"xxx=yyy"} (constant). But 2nd page header didn't include cookie header.
